# AES Traffic Security Assesment

Tags: tls, aes, vulnerability-assessment

Assume we have only access to the traffic between two module (Hardware, Software, ...) and These modules communicate with SSL (PSK).
Is it possible to assess AES encryption of this traffic?
some features like key length, AES cypher mode or any other important parameter

Comment: Are you asking if you just see some AES encrypted traffic if you can infer mode, key length, etc.?

Comment: Yes, something like this, because in some security assessment cases i don't have access to source of traffic (ex: firewall) and i have only encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These modules communicate with SSL (PSK) ...

If these modules use SSL the encryption algorithm (AES, ...) and key length are encoded in the cipher used. Which cipher is used can be seen from the TLS handshake, notably the ServerHello message send by the server.

Answer (score 0):

@steffen-ullrich, your advice was helpful!
I decode my sample traffic as some protocols in wireshark (because there was non-standard ports on traffic) and finally i found 'ServerHello message' and all information i needed!

[image]